# Confirmation before deleting row

Tags: ios, uitableview, uialertview

I'm trying to show a `UIAlertView` before actually deleting a cell from a `UITableView`

```
NSIndexPath *_tmpIndexPath;


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        _tmpIndexPath = indexPath;

         NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row); // 2
         NSLog(@"%d", _tmpIndexPath.row); // 2

        UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Dete" message:@"Are you sure you want to delete this entry?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil] autorelease];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

So both my logs return the correct path.

I have my view delegating the UIAlertView

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"%d", _tmpIndexPath.row);
    if(buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"%d", _tmpIndexPath.row);
    }
}
```

Now I can't figure out why in the `clickButtonAtIndex()` I'm getting an error when trying to log `_tmpIndexPath.row`

```
 *** -[NSIndexPath row]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x12228e00
```

Comment: You can use like this right         UIAlertView *alert;
        [alert setTag:indexPath.row];

Comment: so you will get the row value in clickedButtonAtIndex method..

Comment: Thanks, I was indeed looking for something like that too

Comment: Sorry, I thought you have not seen my comment so, I have posted that as a answer also..;)

Comment: It was :) Just not the answer to this question, but I was looking for something like that too previously

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you will need to retain the indexPath, what is happening is that your indexPath when the alert is dismissed is already deallocated from your system,

Like this

Change

```
_tmpIndexPath = indexPath;
```

to

```
_tmpIndexPath = [indexPath retain];
```

Comment: That was indeed the solution, thanks. (will accept as answer in 5 min)

Answer (score 3):

You can try to do this

```
        UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Dete" message:@"Are you sure you want to delete this entry?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil] autorelease];
[alert setTag:indexPath.row];
        [alert show];
```

So you can get the value as

```
[alertView tag]
```

In `clickedButtonAtIndex`

Answer (score 1):

`NSIndexPath` is a `NSObject` and you have it autoreleased in your `tableView: commitEditingStyle` method so assigning it to your instance variable: `_tmpIndexPath = indexPath;` it gets deallocated later. What you need to do is:
`_tmpIndexPath = [indexPath copy];` but be careful because every time you are responsible to release your `_tmpIndexPath` before setting it again. The cleaner solution is to use properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath;
...
self.tmpIndexPath = indexPath;
```

Answer (score 1):

Acknowledging the technical answers above, can I suggest that this isn't actually necessary.  If you are using the normal ways to delete items from a table view (edit button and swipe the row) then adding a confirmation in to the flow is going to be contradictory to how people will expect the table to behave.  The user already has to tap (or swipe) before even gaining access to the delete functionality, so they must already be pretty sure they want to do it.

Comment: I'm actually using the normal way, but we had some complaints from users that they accidentally delete items, the alert is just to make sure they want to delete it. (As it's delete from our servers aswel)

Answer (score 0):

Do you use ARC? If not try _tmpIndexPath = [indexPath retain]; and don't forget release it later